# sql check if join table has rows by mutliple criterias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, assets and asset_params.

assets

```
|asset_id|  some_asset_data |
-----------------------------  
|   1    | 'some data'      |
|   2    | 'some other data'|
```

asset_params

```
|asset_param_id|asset_id|param_name|param_value|  
------------------------------------------------
|       1      |    1   | 'Memory' | '4096'    |    
|       2      |    1   | 'OS'     | 'Windows' |  
|       3      |    2   | 'Memory' | '4096'    |
|       4      |    2   | 'OS'     | 'Linux'   |
```

Now, how can i find assets which have parameters where they have a param called 'Memory' with value '4096' AND a param 'OS' with value 'Windows'.

Desired result is that i find one asset row, with id 1, in the example case.

I cant find a reasonable solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from assets a where
    exists (select 1 from asset_params p
        where name = "OS" and value = "Win" and a.asset_id=p.asset_id)
    and exists (select 1 from asset_params p
        where name = "memory" and value = "4096" and a.asset_id=p.asset_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select asset_id
from asset_params
where param_name = 'Memory' and param_value = '3096' or
      param_name = 'OS' and param_value = 'Windows'
group by asset_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Note:  if you can have multiple parameters with the same name, you should use `count(distinct param_name)` = 2.

This easily generalized.  A more Postgres'ish way of writing it is:

```
select asset_id
from asset_params
where (param_name, param_value) in (('Memory', '3096'),  ('OS', 'Windows'))
group by asset_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: What will happens if your asset has twice the parameter "Memory" with a value of "3096" but not the parameter "OS" with value "Windows"? I think that in this case your count will be at 2 but the result is not the expected result

Comment: I think you should put explicit braces in the `WHERE` part of the first query, to make it look like `WHERE (…) OR (…)`

Comment: @CédricL.Charlier . . . Check the "note".  If the OP can have multiple parameters with the same name, then use `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
select * from assets where
    assets_id in (select assets_id from asset_params
        where name = "OS" and value = "Win")
and
    assets_id in (select assets_id from asset_params
        where name = "memory" and value = "4096")
```

If your tables are huge, this needs proper indexes. But you should always have good indexes anyway. ;)